# WebStorm, empty code blocks, and curly braces

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Every time I "Reformat Code", WebStorm will place a new-line in between any empty curly braces. For example, if I have this code:

`export class Example {}`

and I reformat the code (`Command + Option + L` on mac), I end up with this:

`export class Example {
}`

How can I stop my editor from inserting a new line? WebStorm version is 2016.2

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With these settings it seems to work -- IDE will not break such code into multiple lines but will leave as is.

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript --> Wrapping and Braces`
2. `Keep when reformatting | Simple block in one line` -- checked
3. `Braces placement | In class declaration` -- "End of line"

[image]

Screenshot from PhpStorm 2016.3 ... but it should be the same in 2016.2.

Comment: So this code: `export class Example {}` will get changed to 
`export class Example {[NEW_LINE]}` 
no matter what.

But this code: `constructor() {}` will stay as such if I turn on `Simple methods in one line`.

This is pretty close (since I shouldn't have too many empty classes anyways), so I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The class example remains in single line with my settings -- those 2 changes above is the only thing I've done.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually `Simple methods in one line` option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/common-code-style-options-wrapping-and-braces.html) online help:

Under 
`Braces Placement Options` set **`Braces placement style`** to `Next line if wrapped`

Comment: If I go to `Webstorm -> Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> TypeScript -> Wrapping and Braces` and select `Next line if wrapped` for `Braces placement -> In class declaration`, the OPENING brace gets moved, not the closing brace.

Comment: @exk0730 can you try to set it to `End of line`?

Comment: Yeh, that's what it's defaulted to, I believe. It seems to only control the beginning brace :/